# Selecting Multiple photos from a device's image gallery using PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, gallery

I was able to build a test app based on the camera.getPicture full example in PhoneGap's documentation.  It allows me to take a photo or retrieve a photo from the gallery and place it in a div.

However, I want to be able to select multiple images from the gallery and place each in its own div. Can anyone point me in the right direction to learn how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Here is the javascript I'm using:

```
var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

// Wait for PhoneGap to connect with the device
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// PhoneGap is ready to be used!
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
  var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
  largeImage.style.display = 'block';
  largeImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}


function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
  var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
  largeImage.style.display = 'block';
  largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

// A button will call this function
function capturePhoto() {
    //add new div

    var newPhoto = document.createElement("div");
    newPhoto.id = "div";        
    newPhoto.className ="photo";
    newPhoto.innerHTML = "<img id='largeImage' src='' />";
    document.getElementById("photos").appendChild(newPhoto);


  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50 });
}

// A button will call this function
function getPhoto(source) {
    //add new div



  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}


// Called if something bad happens.
function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
```

Comment: I'm looking for the same - did you ever happen to figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

As of Phonegap 3.5 there is no support for selecting multiple images at the same time.  You will need to write or find a plugin that will work with the native code to enable you to do this.  Here is the issue described in the Phonegap development plan. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1215

I am working on doing this as well.  Here is a link for an Android solution.

[http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.technotalkative.com/android-select-multiple-photos-from-gallery/](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://www.technotalkative.com/android-select-multiple-photos-from-gallery/)

Answer (score -1):

you need to create the div dynamically after every photo is taken.
Your success callback would be something like this:

```
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
    // the following is all one line.
    document.getElementById("photos").innerHTML+=
    "<div>\
         <img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,"+imageData+"\">\
     </div>";
}
```

then you can style all the imgs via css using something like this

```
#photos > div {
    width: 100px;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
}
```